# Почему websocket не отправляет такое значение?

Tags: python, websokets

Пробовал я сделать так же через json.dumps('42["time"]') Но как не странно, он делает вот так: "42["time"]"

В итоге я не знаю как решить проблему, ведь ответа дальше он не присылает, хотя должен. Проблема именно в этом. Ведь на другие сообщения, где не надо отправлять json, ответ приходит.

[image: Как отправляется]

Comment: если шлёте не json, а `42["time"]` точно не json, то и не надо его пытаться раскрывать парсером объектов.

Comment: в браузере показывает этот объект, как json. а ещё, тогда как его правильно отправить? обычным текстом тоже не работает

Comment: Как blob. Чем отправляете в питоне?